How can I filter woocommerce orders list to specific users in the backoffice?
so I run 4 physical stores In 4 different states and I am using wordpress/woocommerce for the online part with “states-cities-and-places-for-woocommerce” plugin.
Each Store Manager has his own credential and I would like to show orders to the store managers with a set of conditions.
Store 1 id = 1 with delivery states = ALL;
Store 2 id = 2 with delivery states = ALL;
Store 3 id = 3 with delivery states = SS, MN, MH;
Store 4 id = 4 with delivery area = BA;

As for the conditions:

I would like the Store 1 & 2 to see all orders, with no restriction.

Store 3: See only orders with pickup in his store or free/paid delivery in his states:


- (shipping_method = 'Pick up at Store 3')
OR
- ((shipping_method = 'Free Delivery') AND (shipping_state = 'SS', 'MN', 'MH'))
OR
- ((shipping_method = 'Paid Delivery') AND (shipping_state = 'SS', 'MN', 'MH'))


Store 4: See only orders with pickup in his store or free/paid delivery in his state:

- (shipping_method = 'Pick up at Store 4');
OR
- ((shipping_method = 'Free Delivery') AND (shipping_state = 'BA'));
OR
- ((shipping_method = 'Paid Delivery') AND (shipping_state = 'BA'));


The problem with the code I wrote, is that whenever a customer use shipping method pick up at store 3 but shipping states different than SS, MN or MH, the order is not displayed for them. Same thing for store 4.
Here is the function I added in the function.php of the child template, what am I doing wrong?
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'restrict_orders_for_shop_managers');
function restrict_orders_for_shop_managers($query) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_order' && is_admin()) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        // Store managers' IDs
        $store_1_id = 1;
        $store_2_id = 2;
        $store_3_id = 3;
        $store_4_id = 4;

        // Store 1 and 3 managers see all orders
        if (in_array($current_user->ID, [$store_1_id, $store_2_id])) {
            return; // Do nothing, show all orders
        }

        // Store Manager 3
        if ($current_user->ID == $store_3_id) {
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_shipping_method',
                    'value' => 'Pick up at Store 3',
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_method',
                        'value' => 'Free Delivery',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_state',
                        'value' => array('SS', 'MN', 'MH'),
                        'compare' => 'IN'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_method',
                        'value' => 'Paid Delivery',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_state',
                        'value' => array('SS', 'MN', 'MH'),
                        'compare' => 'IN'
                    )
                )
            );
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        }

        // Store 4
        if ($current_user->ID == $store_4_id) {
            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_shipping_method',
                    'value' => 'Pick up at Store 4',
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_method',
                        'value' => 'Free Delivery',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_state',
                        'value' => 'BA',
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_method',
                        'value' => 'Paid Delivery',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => '_shipping_state',
                        'value' => 'BA',
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
                )
            );
            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        }
    }
}


"but shipping states different than SS, MN or MH" if you have 'relation' => 'AND', wont show it.
